# converse of a rate of convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Q) Let $p>0$, $X_i's$ be i.i.d. with $EX_1 = 0$. If $S_n/n^{1/p}\rightarrow 0$ a.s., then prove that $E|X_1|^p<\infty$.

Let $E|X_1|^p = \infty\implies E|X_1|^p = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(|X_n|>n^{1/p})=\infty$ and thus by BC lemma $|X_n|/n^{1/p} \geq 1 $ i.o. with probability $1$. How can I relate $S_n$ to $|X_n|$ so as to arrive at a contradiction? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac {X_n} {n^{1/p}}=\frac {S_n} {n^{1/p}}-\frac {S_{n-1}} {(n-1)^{1/p}} \frac {(n-1)^{1/p}} {n^{1/p}} \to 0$